# Bootstrap media queries mixins

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I recently taught myself how to use Bootstrap, and I am trying to use the responsive media queries that are available as Sass mixins (Note I have never used Sass before). I can't get the @include media-breakpoint queries to work. The screenshot below shows an example of how I have tried using it in Atom. It seems to me that Atom is not recognizing the syntax, even though the Bootstrap cdn is linked to my index file. What am I missing? Thanks.

[example Bootstrap mixin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qGXn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a mixin that integrates with Bootstrap's screen size variables. You could always replace the variable with your own custom size.

```
@mixin tablet {
    @media (min-width: #{$screen-sm}) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

And here's an example of how you might use it in a stylesheet:

```
.foo {
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 15px;

    @include tablet {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't I be able to use the predefined mixins? That is basically what their instructions say, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/. Do you have an idea why Atom isn't recognizing it?

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out, that in order to use their predefined mixins I would need to download the sass source files. Thanks for your help.